# A function to check whether a box is checked or not in PHP

Tags: php, html, for-loop, checkbox, foreach

I am trying to get a grasp on how to properly understand how POST works and decided to make a little PHP program that generates 100 checkboxes, and at the click of the button on the top of the document, a function is called that loops through all of the checkboxes and states whether or not they are checked. However, it seems like the way I am implementing it does not work.

Here is a more sequential step by step process of what I was thinking as I was writing this script, I would appreciate if someone could tell me the flaw in my thinking.

1. Create a button in a form with `method=post`.
2. Create an array in PHP to store all the checkbox names.
3. Create a for loop. In each iteration of the loop, a string is created with the format of `#checkbox` so each checkbox has its own unique identifier. Each one of these strings is stored in an array. PHP then echo's out a form with `method=post` with a checkbox inside each form. Each checkbox has its unique name.
4. After each checkbox is created, you can see if each checkbox is checked or not by clicking the button, which calls the `checkFunction()` function.
5. In the function, there is a `foreach` loop. This loop goes through each element in the array to fetch the checkbox name, uses `isset` to see if the checkbox is checked or not, and echo's out if it is.

This seems simple enough to me, but it doesn't seem to work for whatever reason. Could anyone shed some light as to why not?

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Checked Boxes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post"> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit_checked" class="button" value="Check if checkbox is checked"/> 
        </form> 

        <?php
            $checkboxNames = array();
            for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
                $checkboxStr=$x."checkbox";
                $checkboxNames[] = $checkboxStr;
                echo "<form method=\"post\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"$checkboxStr\" value=\"$checkboxStr\">$checkboxStr</form>";
            }

            echo("<hr>");
            echo("<h2>Status of Checkboxes:</h2>");

            function checkFunction(){
                foreach ($checkboxNames as $currentName){
                    if (isset($_POST["$currentName"]))
                        echo("<p>$currentName is checked!</p>");
                    else
                        echo("<p>$currentName is not checked!</p>");
                }
            }

            if(isset($_POST['submit_checked']))
                checkFunction();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to remove form tag in `foreach`, you should only use 1 `<form method="post">`  in a form. And put checkbox inputs inside your main form;
2. PHP function cant access variable outside that function, so you should put that variable in params.

Below is the working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Checked Boxes</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_checked" class="button" value="Check if checkbox is
    checked"/><br>

    <?php
    $checkboxNames = array();
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
        $checkboxStr     = $x."checkbox";
        $checkboxNames[] = $checkboxStr;
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"$checkboxStr\" value=\"$checkboxStr\">$checkboxStr <br>";
    }

    echo("<hr>");
    echo("<h2>Status of Checkboxes:</h2>");

    function checkFunction($checkboxNames)
    {
        foreach ($checkboxNames as $currentName) {
            if (isset($_POST[$currentName])) {
                echo("<p>$currentName is checked!</p>");
            } else {
                echo("<p>$currentName is not checked!</p>");
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit_checked'])) {
        checkFunction($checkboxNames);
    }
    ?>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting the first form only while all your checkboxes are in separate forms that are not being submitted. Try to rewrite your loop to have checkbox inputs inside your main form.